# java sql query on data imported from csv file

Tags: java, sql, csv, jdbc, multidimensional-array

I am planning a Java program which is working with data in csv files which I will load into 2D arrays or a hash map or some other object.  I am curious if Java has any library or anything that would permit the implementation of SQL statements to query subsets from internally stored data objects.

I am wondering if maybe the JBDC drivers that allow Java to connect with or control relational SQL databases can be applied to internal data objects.

Comment: Have you considered an in-memory database (e.g., MemSQL)?

Comment: There is a linux tool named Q (https://github.com/harelba/q) that you can use in the terminal to apply sql commands on a csv. Not what you are looking for but perhaps if you install this in your enviornment then you can execute the Q command through java

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to use h2 with the inbuilt csv support. You can find more details here http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv . I like this approach since this allows you to query / manipulate the data in a way a jdbc statement allows you to.

Comment: HSQLDB supports [text tables](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/texttables-chapt.html), too.

Answer (score 1):

There's also this [JDBC driver](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/index.html) that allows you to query CSV files directly using SQL.